# How do I convert pandas data frame to GeoJson overlay in folium

Tags: python, html, pandas, request, folium

[I have this code here but the thing is when I do folium.GeoJson(data, name="geojson") it just returns ValueError: Cannot render objects with any missing geometries: 0      {'type': 'MultiPolygon', 'coordinates': [[[[-7....

````
import requests 
import json
import pandas as pd
import folium
map = folium.Map(location=\[40, -73\], zoom_start=6, tiles="OpenStreetMap")
fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Parks", show = False)
map.add_child(fg)
park_data = requests.get("https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/enfh-gkve.json")
park_data = park_data.json()
park_frame = pd.DataFrame(data=park_data)
park_geo_data = park_frame["multipolygon"]
fg.add_child(folium.GeoJson(park_geo_data, name = "Parks"))
map.add_child(folium.LayerControl(position="topright"))
map.save("about.html")
``` See image for what the data looks like raw from the rest api][1] 


[Shows error as well as shows what raw rest api response looks like][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGSqL.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlKdS.png
````

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the rows of your dataframe and add row's 'multipolygon' column as your geojson feature to the featureGroup.

```
park_data = pd.read_json("https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/enfh-gkve.json")
for i, row in park_data.iterrows():
    geo_data = row['multipolygon']
    fg.add_child(folium.GeoJson(geo_data))
```

Comment: thanks but why do we need the "i" in the for loop

Comment: "i" is the index column of your dataframe, you don't need it as such. Its my habit to use it so that I can keep track if something fails to know where to look